Custom shape with clip-path


div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
   background-color: green;
   height: 50vh;
   width: 100vw;
}
<div></div>



Is it possible to do this kind of shape with clip-path and svg? I need to have this kind of modal which comes from bottom to up on mobile devices
The requirements are:

This place with Lorem... can have different height depending on content
The "hill"/shape should be always the same size independen on mobile device width
I should be able to apply any background with color or image for entire element



Please give us some sort of code so we can help you. We can't help with an issue which we don't know the code for.

@Lil_PhyziX I put the code

the hill shape being the same size will require javascript to keep the size the same as the page width changes.

So, are you trying to figure out how to add the "hill" like affect on the popup? I need clarification.

So you need to figure out what JS code would work correct?

@Lil_PhyziX I crearly described what I need. Yes, I need hill like effect, rounded sides as presented and possibility to put as background anything

Alright. I will provide an answer shortly once I figure this out.

@Lil_PhyziX thank you, I will be grateful

I personally didn't know how to do this entirely, so went onto reddit and found a few things, and put this code together. some of which I made, and some of which is code examples I took and modified. Try using this.
HTML:
<div class="modal">
  <div class="content">
    <!-- Your dynamic content goes here -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  </div>
  <svg class="hill-shape" viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0,10 Q50,0 100,10 Z" fill="green" />
  </svg>
</div>

CSS:
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: transparent; /* Set your desired background color or image */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide the overflowing hill shape */
}

.content {
  padding: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

.hill-shape {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px; /* Adjust the height of the hill shape */
  fill: green; /* Same color as the background */
}


The .modal div contains your dynamic content (e.g., text, images).

The .hill-shape SVG element creates the “hill” shape using a quadratic Bezier curve (Q) path.

Adjust the viewBox and path coordinates to fit your desired shape and size.

The preserveAspectRatio="none" ensures the SVG scales proportionally.

The fill property sets the color of the hill shape (same as the background).


